# Bonobo Git Server 5.0.0 - Cookies Authentication fails

Tags: authentication, cookies, bonobo

I've setup a fresh bonobo server on win8.

When trying to login with admin:admin the login page apears again and I'm not logged in.

When trying to login with invalid credentials I get the expected error: 
"The username or password provided is incorrect"

Bonobo.Git.Server.Errors.log is:

Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"... w3wp.exe Error: 0 : Server Error occured and caught in Global.asax - System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Der Server kann den Header nicht anhängen, nachdem HTTP-Header gesendet wurden.    bei System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary 2 headers, String key, String[] values)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, String key, String value, CookieOptions options)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.d__f.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__b.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__8.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__0.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.d__5.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    bei Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.d__2.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---    bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    bei Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)    bei System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() bei System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed with 5.0.1.